# NSURLConnection data coming back empty

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsurlconnection

I can't figure out why my code isn't working.  I think I'm doing everything correctly, the php script encodes and displays how it should.  Can someone please look over my code and suggest what I'm doing wrong?

PHP:

```
$link = ...succesfully connects
if ($link){
    if (isset($_REQUEST['past'])) {
        $result = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT * FROM messages WHERE id > '.
            mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['past']).
            ' ORDER BY added LIMIT 50');
        $messages = array();
        echo json_encode($messages);
    } else {
        $result = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY timeadded LIMIT 50');
        $messages = array();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $messages[] = $row;
        }
        echo json_encode($messages);
    }
}
```

The output is like this:

```
[{"id":"1","user":"me","message":"my first message","timeadded":"2014-02-11 12:47:55"},{"id":"2","user":"me","message":"my second message","timeadded":"2014-02-18 14:29:23"}]
```

Here's my ViewController code:

```
h:
{
NSMutableData *responseData;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *receivedData;


m:
@synthesize receivedData;

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
[responseData setLength:0];
NSLog(@"received response");
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
[responseData appendData:data];
NSLog(@"%@", receivedData);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[responseData length]);
receivedData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@", responseData);
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[self getNewMessages];
}

- (void)getNewMessages {
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"messages.php?past=%d", lastId] relativeToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mydomain.com/"]];

responseData = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:0];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

 NSURLConnection *conn=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
 if (conn)
 {
     receivedData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
     NSLog(@"sent request to server");
 }
}
```

I'm just trying to log the array after it gets deserialized but it comes up empty in the log.  The first two logs get displayed and then just ().  What am I doing wrong here?  The app builds and runs just fine, no errors...thanks in advance!

If I add a NSMutableData variable and try to do it like in the documentation, the data I get in the didReceiveData function look like this: <5b5d>.  What does that mean?

Here's my response received:

```
{ status code: 200, headers {
Connection = "Keep-Alive";
"Content-Type" = "text/html";
Date = "Wed, 19 Feb 2014 00:03:30 GMT";
"Keep-Alive" = "timeout=10, max=30";
Server = Apache;
"Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
Vary = "Accept-Encoding";
} }
```

ANSWER:  So apparently the PHP script was wrong...it didn't like isset.  Once I got rid of that, I got my data to return.  Following the iOS documentation, everything worked like it should.

Comment: I also tried using just NSData dataWithContentsOfUrl but I figured this is more of a proper way to connect.  Still in both cases I got an empty array

Comment: I would add some logic in `connection:didReceiveResponse:` that casts the `response` variable to a `NSHTTPURLResponse` and then check the status code (in case you're getting something other than 200).

Comment: Did you call the START method? i.e [conn start]; try using initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately: might work better for you if you like to make the request happen straight away

Comment: @PaulDardeau I logged the response and it is 200...

Comment: @ShamsAhmed changed my connection request to immediately...still got the empty array...

Comment: have u run to 'echo json_encode($messages);'?

Answer (score 1):

You're not using connection:didReceiveData: correctly. You should create an NSMutableData instance, and append the data received in connection:didReceiveData: to it. You should do the conversion to your array in connectionDidFinishLoading: which you haven't implemented. Look at the code Apple shows in the "URL Loading System Programming Guide" for an example.

Comment: I tried that after posting this post but I still get the same output in the FinishLoading...Can you look over my updated code and see what's wrong now?  The output is still the same <5b5d> after deserializing it into a MutableArray.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the document for your reference from this link. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
// Append the new data to the instance variable you declared
[_responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
// The request is complete and data has been received
// You can parse the stuff in your instance variable now
NSLog(@"%@", [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_responseData options:kNilOptions error:nil]);
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
// The request has failed for some reason!
// Check the error var
}
```

Comment: I did try that last night.  I updated my original question with the new code and I still get the same thing...with the log of <5b5d>.  What does that mean?  I swear I have everything the same as the documentation guide...

Comment: Change like this.. Assign return object of NSJSONSerialization to dictioanry. `- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[responseData length]);
NSDictionary *responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@", responseDict);
}`

Comment: I tried that, also tried mutable options.  In every case I get that <5b5d> before deserialization and an empty array/dictionary after.  I tried just doing NSData dataWithContentsOfUrl and same result.  The response is 200, that means it connected the PHP script and got something back but what it got back is empty?  Is there a problem with php?

Comment: I finally got it to work by deleting the extra parameter off the URL string...do you know how I can get that to work with the parameter ?past=%d", lastId?